# How to autoload custom class in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I wrote custom class with method that returns array.

I need to autoload this class like Auth() class in Laravel, that I could get access to it from any controller not using `use`

Comment: Add it to your composer.json. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

Answer (score 1):

Create one custom helper file

and add function

```
if (! function_exists('yourcustomclass')) {

    function yourcustomclass()
    {
        use App\Http\yourcustomclassname;
        return new yourcustomclassname()
    }
}
```

you can use yourcustomclass() function from anywhere to get yourcustomclassname class object

Answer (score 0):

When accessing class/function from other namespace than you're currently  in you have to use Fully-Qualified Class Name (or type `use`, but you don't want to do that), so instead of `Auth::user()` you need to write `\Auth::user()`

`\` at the beginning means that class is located in root namespace

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write super method(s) in **App\Http\Controllers\Controller**?

Simply call super method(s) in the subclass which extends **Controller**